# Background scrolling in Android

Tags: android, layout, gridview, background, scroll

I have application that display books (a kind of library shelves).
My books are displayed as GridView.
Now I trying to set background image (book shelves).

When I set android:background property of GridView, it shows background image, but in case of many books when user scroll them, the only images of books are scrolling, not a shelves. The shelves has fixed position.

How can I solve it? I need scrolling of GridView images and also background, like in web-browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: @Seigei Delphis did u found the solution..!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first way I can think of to approach your problem is to set the background on each individual view within your GridView to a tile, which when combined with other tiles produces a bookshelf-like appearance.

Or you could maybe change the GridView to scroll horizontally and the problem might be solved. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jon. The second solution is quite original :))

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `GridView`, and override `dispatchDraw`.
This is inspired by [ShelvesView](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view/ShelvesView.java).

The code below is tested, you should be able to do it. `bgBitmap` is the tiling bitmap.

```
@Override protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    final int top = count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;

    if (p == null) {
        p = new Paint();
        p.setShader(new BitmapShader(bgBitmap, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT));
    }

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, top);
    canvas.drawPaint(p); 
    canvas.restore();

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```